# How to fix an error occurred while from the store provider's data reader after I added code to Global.asax?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Normally, I do not have any error but, after I added the below code to Global.asax , I had a **system.data.entity.core.entitycommandexecutionexception: 'an error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. see the inner exception for details.' error.** Here is code where I got error;

```
public ActionResult Chartjs(String makineadi, DateTime? startdate, DateTime? enddate)
    {
        var data = entities.Database.SqlQuery<chartjs>("SELECT Sıcaklık AS sıcak, Recete_Sure as sure, Tarih as tarih From Recete Where Machine_IP ='" + makineadi + "' and Tarih between'" + startdate + "' and '" + enddate + "'").ToList();
        ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

And here is my database ;

```
 public class chartjs
        {
            public int sıcak { get; set; }
            public int sure { get; set; }
            public DateTime tarih { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is my global.asax code, (I used this to make my project multi-language);

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Language"];
        if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr");
        }
    }
```

If I will delete it, I got no error.

Comment: Did you delete cookies? Cookies may be remembering the old version.

Comment: I tried it, but I think my main problem is about to convert varchar to datetime while I selected startdate and endate, it could be about datetime format, how can I make proper it to all over the world

Comment: The DateTim.ParseExact accepts an array of formats so you may not need the culture.  See : public static DateTime ParseExact(string s, string[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style);  And use System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None

Comment: I tried it, but It did not work, if I choose start date and end date in English mode it worked, but If I make my page in Turkish I got an error that is caused of convert varchar to datetime

Comment: Turkish the letters go from right to left.

Comment: No, It is not true

Comment: I fixed it, thanks @jdweng